# Assigning object to variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a list object in that I m retriving details of perticular id. so i have code like this,

```
<c:forEach var="teacherView" items="${teacherInfoById}">
<c:if test="${teacherView.getTeacherId()==param.teacherId}">
<c:out value="${teacherView.getTeacherId()}" />
<c:set var="teacherId" scope="session" value="teacherView"></c:set>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

it is working fine but in next line I am getting error,

```
id:<c:out value="${teacherId.getTeacherId()}"></c:out>
```

I think the variable cant access outside the foreach can any one help in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `${}` in value attribute of `<c:set` change this line:

```
<c:set var="teacherId" scope="session" value="teacherView"></c:set>
```

to

```
<c:set var="teacherId" scope="session" value="${teacherView}"/>
```